# How get the name of the days of the week in Dart

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

Somebody knows how can I extract from DateTime the name of the day of the week?

ej:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String dateFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm').format(date);
```

Result -> Friday

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Use 'EEEE' as a date pattern

```
 DateFormat('EEEE').format(date); /// e.g Thursday
```

Don't forget to import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Check this for more info : https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Viewer's can disappointed, please mention need to add intl package

Answer (score 51):

in your **pubspec.yaml** file, dependencies section.
add **intl** dependency like so :

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.16.0 // <-- dependency added here, remember to remove this comment
  // other dependencies . remove this comment too
```

more about intl dependency here :
[intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install)

> This package provides internationalization and localization facilities, including message translation, plurals and genders, date/number formatting and parsing, and bidirectional text.

and then at the top of your dart file import :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

now you can use DateFormat as you wish, here is an example :

```
var date = DateTime.now();
print(date.toString()); // prints something like 2019-12-10 10:02:22.287949
print(DateFormat('EEEE').format(date)); // prints Tuesday
print(DateFormat('EEEE, d MMM, yyyy').format(date)); // prints Tuesday, 10 Dec, 2019
print(DateFormat('h:mm a').format(date)); // prints 10:02 AM
```

there are many formats you can use with DateFormat, more details found here :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

hope this helps.
Thank you

Answer (score 47):

You can just use .weekday method to find out the day .
eg:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.now();
 print("weekday is ${date.weekday}");
```

This will return the weekday number, for eg tuesday is 2 , as shown below

```
class DateTime implements Comparable<DateTime> {
      // Weekday constants that are returned by [weekday] method:
      static const int monday = 1;
      static const int tuesday = 2;
      static const int wednesday = 3;
      static const int thursday = 4;
      static const int friday = 5;
      static const int saturday = 6;
      static const int sunday = 7;
      static const int daysPerWeek = 7;
```

Comment: You did not understand the OP's question. He asked for a name, not a number.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going to ask a question just about this. Getting the day of the week as an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below method to achieve the desired result. The return statement can be changed according to your preference.
(This is if you want to skip the use of the intl package)

```
String dateFormatter(DateTime date) {
  dynamic dayData =
      '{ "1" : "Mon", "2" : "Tue", "3" : "Wed", "4" : "Thur", "5" : "Fri", "6" : "Sat", "7" : "Sun" }';

  dynamic monthData =
      '{ "1" : "Jan", "2" : "Feb", "3" : "Mar", "4" : "Apr", "5" : "May", "6" : "June", "7" : "Jul", "8" : "Aug", "9" : "Sep", "10" : "Oct", "11" : "Nov", "12" : "Dec" }';

  return json.decode(dayData)['${date.weekday}'] +
      ", " +
      date.day.toString() +
      " " +
      json.decode(monthData)['${date.month}'] +
      " " +
      date.year.toString();
}
```

You can call the above method as

```
dateFormatter(DateTime.now())
```

The produces the result -  Sat, 11 Apr 2020

Answer (score 5):

Extensions are good solutions. You can do it for weekday also.
Before you use, call once DateTimeExtension to see getMonthString()

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  String getMonthString() {
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return 'Jan.';
      case 2:
        return 'Feb.';
      case 3:
        return 'Mar.';
      case 4:
        return 'Apr.';
      case 5:
        return 'May';
      case 6:
        return 'Jun.';
      case 7:
        return 'Jul.';
      case 8:
        return 'Aug.';
      case 9:
        return 'Sept.';
      case 10:
        return 'Oct.';
      case 11:
        return 'Nov.';
      case 12:
        return 'Dec.';
      default:
        return 'Err';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to use `intl` package as seen in other answers, but if you want to code your own solution you can do something like:

```
const Map<int, String> weekdayName = {1: "Monday", 2: "Tuesday", 3: "Wednesday", 4: "Thursday", 5: "Friday", 6: "Saturday", 7: "Sunday"};
print(weekdayName[DateTime.now().weekday]);
```

or you can extend DateTime class, doing something like:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  String? weekdayName() {
    const Map<int, String> weekdayName = {1: "Monday", 2: "Tuesday", 3: "Wednesday", 4: "Thursday", 5: "Friday", 6: "Saturday", 7: "Sunday"};
    return weekdayName[weekday];
  }
}
print(DateTime.now().weekdayName());
```

you can test these solutions in [DartPad1](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0aaa4a21564d0d7b5994c518cf3b68c8) and [DartPad2](https://dartpad.dev/?id=93281c9ce61e871f0b633d33214ccff4)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the localised name here is the bulletproof solution for a **dedicated weekday**.

You need to be a bit tricky.

Let's design the API:

```dart
String getWeekdayName(int weekday)
```

We surely know that we can get the weekday from `DateTime`:

```
DateTime.weekday // returns ISO value
```

It returns an ISO value (**Monday = 1, Sunday = 7**)

We also know that to get the "Monday", "Tuesday" (or any localised value) we can do:

```
DateFormat('EEEE').format(date);  // returns String
```

So how to get the name for `int weekday`?

**We should create `DateTime` somehow with `weekday` and then format it accordingly.**

We must also commit to passing an ISO-compliant value for the `weekday`, which is in `<1,7>` range.

Solution:

```
String getWeekdayName(int weekday) {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now().toLocal();
    final int diff = now.weekday - weekday; // weekday is our 1-7 ISO value
    var udpatedDt;
    if (diff > 0) {
        udpatedDt = now.subtract(Duration(days: diff));
    } else if (diff == 0) {
        udpatedDt = now;
    } else {
        udpatedDt = now.add(Duration(days: diff * -1));
    }
    final String weekdayName = DateFormat('EEEE').format(udpatedDt);
    return weekdayName;
}
```