# Need current week day name with date which can be used further

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I need This current weeks day name, with the date like (01/12/2020). I can select the data, so that I can use the data further.

Comment: see below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371874/how-get-the-name-of-the-days-of-the-week-in-dart

Comment: no is not, i need select option of 7 days.

Comment: What does "select option of 7 days" mean?  Your question is very unclear.  As stated, you want to take a date (e.g. January 12, 2020) and derive the weekday name ("Sunday"), which is what the cited question already answers.  It sounds like you want something else?

Answer (score 1):

***///////////////////////////////////////////////////////  BUILD YOUR OWN
///////////////////////////////////////////////***

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
      dependencies:
          intl: ^0.16.1
```

Import the package in the dart file

```
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

    ...

    var dateString = '01/12/2020';
    var date = DateFormat('d/M/yyyy').parse(dateString);


    List<String> daysInWeek=['Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday',];
    print(daysInWeek[date.weekday-1]);
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the order of the days of the week.

Comment: I don't know how could I, It's crazy. Sorry fixed it.

Comment: This code does not work. This will consistently return the incorrect day of the week.

Comment: Fixed it again.

Comment: This just further breaks the code.

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: Try your own code for a few different dates. You're going to get the incorrect day of the week and occasionally range/out of bounds errors.

Comment: now it's working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221425/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-amon-chowdhury).

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're wanting is the actual name of the day of the week. In that case, this should do the trick:

```
  var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  var day = DateTime.parse('2020-09-12').weekday;
  print(days[day]); // prints "Saturday"
```

*Try pasting this code in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev) to see how it works*

Comment: This code doesn't work for dates like `2020-09-13`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sunday is supposed to be at index 7. The first index doesn't actually get used. Dart's `weekday` returns 1-7, not 0-6 as I thought.

Comment: So it *does* work. If you have the indices in the order according to the Dart documentation. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sunday works just fine. I tested it. With the day you originally stated, today's date