# How to get all dates and weekdays in current month in flutter

Tags: flutter, date, datetime, datetime-format, weekday

I want to get current months all dates and weekdays like below image

i get all dates with below code

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
late DateTime lastDayOfMonth;
lastDayOfMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);

  Row(
    children: List.generate(
       lastDayOfMonth.day,
        (index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
          child: Text(
            "${index + 1}",
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

but i didn't get weekdays according dates

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lastDayOfMonth` is a single date, therefore using `lastDayOfMonth.weekDay` gives a single day based on `lastDayOfMonth`. We can add duration on `lastDayOfMonth` and find day name.

```dart
 final currentDate =
           lastDayOfMonth.add(Duration(days: index + 1));
```

This will provide update date based on `index`. I am using [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package or create a map to get the day name.

A useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54371874/10157127) about date format.

```dart
 Row(
  children: List.generate(
    lastDayOfMonth.day,
    (index) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            "${index + 1}",
          ),
          () {
            final currentDate =
                lastDayOfMonth.add(Duration(days: index + 1));

            final dateName =
                DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
            return Text(dateName);
          }()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```