# How can I get day name from string date '22 May 2022' in flutter

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart, flutter-datetime-picker

I am a beginner in Flutter, I want to get day name `[like Sunday]` from a date, date i am getting from api which is basically a string like `'22 May 2022'`

How can i get that from this date `'22 May 2022'` ? Can anyone help me? any help should be appreciated

I have tried this but not working for me.

[How get the name of the days of the week in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371874/how-get-the-name-of-the-days-of-the-week-in-dart)

Comment: See [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/) for parsing a `DateTime` object, and then see [How to format DateTime in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579546/) for obtaining the weekday name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
final dateName = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateFormat("DD MMMM yyyy").parse('22 May 2022'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it:

> ```
> import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
>
> //--------------------
>
> final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
>
> final DateFormat format1 = DateFormat('EEE');
> final DateFormat format2 = DateFormat('EEEE');
>
> print(format1.format(today)); // abbreviated, exp. : Sun, Mon, Tue, ...
> print(format2.format(today)); // not abbreviated, exp. : Suday, Monday,...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`final dateName = DateFormat('MEd').format(DateFormat("DD MMMM yyyy").parse('22 May 2022'));`

You can check there all format date
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String daysOfTheWeek = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());
```

// Sunday