# Dart: previous and next weekday name

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

Is there any way in dart to find next and previous weekday name?
Such as, today is say Friday, so previous day was Thursday and next day will Saturday. Can I programmatically handle that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get the name of the days of the week in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371874/how-get-the-name-of-the-days-of-the-week-in-dart)

Comment: Not actually. I have seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time I posted this it's Thursday where I live

For yesterday:

```
print(DateFormat("EEEE").format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -1))));
```

output:

```
Wednesday
```

For tomorrow:

```
print(DateFormat("EEEE").format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1))));
```

Output:

```
Friday
```

The output might be different depending on your locale.

This needs

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

to work.

Comment: This is dangerous on the days that are 23 or 25 hours long (at DST shifts).  See my videos https://youtu.be/usFSVUEadyo and https://youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU for details.

Answer (score 0):

in your pubspec.yaml file, dependencies section. add intl dependency like so

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^latest version
```

and then  import :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

now you can use DateFormat as you wish, here is an example :

```
print(DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now())); // prints Tuesday
print(DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1))));// prints Monday
print(DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)))); // prints Wednesday
```